# Alternative Systems of Monarchy Succession

Tags: royalty

Looking for any alternative systems of hereditary monarchy. Know that the first-born son was generally the accepted back in the day & that England just instituted first-born of any sex. There's lots of ways to flip that script (first-born female for instance) but I am also looking for any other ways that hereditary monarchy has been passed down that isn't typical.

Comment: History.SE might be a good place to ask about what approaches have been done in the past.

Comment: Er, I'm not sure what you're asking - hereditary means passing through a bloodline, first from parents to children, and following by age down and up and sideways to establish a line of succession.  The inheritance can be sex-linked (boy or girl), or include more distant relations when no one closer qualifies.  So if you're not using that script (or variations thereof) to pass down the title, as your asking for alternates seems to imply - then it wouldn't be a hereditary monarchy to begin with.  Maybe you could elaborate on what system you have and what you would like to see?

Comment: So, why on hold?   It's a good question and ideas are interesting.

Comment: @CharlesMerriam and Erin, the main issue is that the question contains no constraints.  This simply means that if there are 50 answers (I could probably come up with that many variations of hereditary monarchy) there is nothing to differentiate what makes one answer better than any other.  A bit more definition on what you are trying to accomplish and we can create an answer tailored to the situation at hand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Primogeniture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primogeniture) is the eldest-son system, and Absolute Primogeniture is the eldest-child system. All of the monarchies in the British Commonwealth recently adopted the latter system; trying to name them all as "England" is incorrect, and insulting.

[Agnatic Succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrilineality#Agnatic_succession) is inheritance by whoever is most closely related to the first king, tracing the relationship only through males. This was the usual system in continental Europe for centuries, but has now been replaced by absolute primogeniture, except in Liechtenstein. If females are entirely excluded, this is "Salic Law" which applies in Japan and Liechtenstein; if they can inherit when there are no male heirs, it's "semi-Salic."

[Rota systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rota_system) involve all the sons of a king getting a chance at ruling, eldest first, before the eldest's eldest son starts a new generation. The point of this is to avoid younger sons trying to kill their elders.

[Agnatic seniority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnatic_seniority) has the king's brothers succeeding before any sons. This is the system in Saudi Arabia, sort of.

You can also have systems where the monarch appoints their heir, and monarchies where succession is decided by some kind of election, like that of the Pope. For both of these, there's usually some limited group who are eligible for election or appointment, such as members of a dynasty, or holders of a high office.

More systems are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_succession). There are a *lot* of variations.

Comment: Note that Salic Law also means you can't inherit *through* your mother.  If your mother's father was the king, then under the Salic system, you are entirely out of the line of succession.

Answer (score 5):

There are few tongue in cheek methods:

- Primogeniture Guardsmenship is the system of the ruling by the eldest (surviving) son.  When the King is a bit of an inbred wuss, this son is fathered by the Capitan of the Guard.
- Retroactive Mandate is the system of law governing the succession of ruling and arbiter of the divine mandate of heaven.   When the previous leader dies and a quick bloodbath delivers a single new candidate, the rules are revised so that of course it has always been true that only the tallest redhead can be king.   The resulting rule system looks a bit like Fizz-bin.
- Wearer of the Crown.  The King is the one wearing the crown.  Upon death, the new king is the one that can arrive wearing the crown.

Answer (score 4):

Some weird but not insane systems:

- The crown goes to the *oldest* child, nephew or sibling of the king who is not yet 30 years old. This will usually lead to an adult on the throne who has a couple of decades to rule, you don't have a child ruler or somebody dragged out of retirement. Princes who turn 30 have a couple of decades to find a niche in the kingdom's administration.
- The crown goes to the *oldest* child who has a heir himself/herself. That assures the succession goes only to fertile rulers who can have heirs. Of course that could be problematic for males, lots of conspiracy theories.
- The crown goes to the *second* child or the second son. The firstborn is expected to go to the clergy, the military, whatever. If the top general is related to the king but not in line for the throne, that might stabilize the dynasty. Unless he wants to change the rules.
- The crown goes to the husband or wife of the oldest child. That keeps the kingdom in the family, but the current ruler can select a suitable successor.

Comment: Marriage is a contract, and in case of royals, that contract stipulates who will inherit what. First son will inherit his father's kingdom, first daughter will inherit her mother's duchy. Or vice-versa.